# Who are the germa 66?

Tags: one-piece

Just finished reading the chapter 828 and I have to say the germa 66 has me blown away.

Who exactly are they? Are they pirates? Are they nobility like the tenryubito?

Did I miss a chapter or something? Can someone fill me in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The answer below has pontetial spoilers, because the animated series hasn't catched up with the manga. Proceed with caution!*

**SPOILERS**

> [Germa 66 or Warmongers](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Germa_66) as they have been called is an
>  organization which is controlled by [Vinsmoke family](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vinsmoke_Family), which
>  recently we found out is [Sanji's](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sanji) family. They have ties with the
>  [Underwold](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Underworld) and recently with [Big Mom Pirates](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Linlin), because of the
>  marriage/alliance of [Sanji](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sanji) and [Purin](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Purin).  As for the nobility
>  Vinsmoke family as [Reiju](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vinsmoke_Reiju) said even though they don't own any
>  land, they are still participate at the [Reverie](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Reverie)
>  *So to summarize, Germa 66 is an organization that is under the Vinsmoke Family and has a lot of weapons/technology at their disposal. They are not pirates and they have affliction with the nobles not directly but indirectly through Vinsmoke Family.
>  This is all we know so far.

Anything that you might need to know is in the one piece wikia [Germa 66](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Germa_66)